# For which real values of $a$ is the sequence defined by $u_1=0$, $u_{n+1}=a\cos{(u_n)}$ dense in some interval?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

For which real values of $a$ is the sequence defined by $u_1=0$, $u_{n+1}=a\cos{(u_n)}$ dense in some interval?

On a graph showing $y=a\cos{x}$ and $y=x$, I start at the point $(0, a\cos{0})$, then go across to  $y=x$, then go up/down to $y=a\cos{x}$, then repeat, ad infinitum.

Using Excel, I have found that, for many values of $a$, a clear pattern emerges in this path. For example, if $a=1$, the path is a spiral towards the intersection of $y=\cos{x}$ and $y=x$. If $a=1.5$, the path approaches a rectangle with vertices at $(p,1.5\cos{p})$ and $(q,1.5\cos{q})$ where $p$ and $q$ are the smallest and largest roots of $1.5\cos{(1.5\cos{x})}=x$.

For which real values of $a$ will the path hit points on $y=a\cos{x}$ whose *y*-coordinates are arbitrarily close to every value in some interval?

(Context: I was playing around with recursively-defined sequences involving trigonometric functions, and this question arose.)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer.

If the sequence converges, say $x_k \to x_*$, it must converge to a fixed point of $g(x)=a \cos x$, i.e a solution of the equation $x = a\cos x$. this happens simply because
$$
x_{k+1} = a \cos x_k \Rightarrow \lim x_{x_{k+1}} = \lim a \cos x_k \Rightarrow x_* = a \cos x_*
$$

The fixed point theorem provides sufficient conditions for the sequence to converge, namely when $g$ is invariant and contractive. You can obtain a bifurcation diagram. The picture below corresponds to starting always with $x_0=0$ and, for increasing $a$, record the limit cycles.

[image]

It sure seems that for some of $a$ may result in dense orbits.

Zooming in:

[image]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants

Comment: Yes @GEdgar, this is quite standard in discrete dynamical systems.

Comment: The graph shows white "columns" around $a=2.05$, $a=2.17$ and $a=2.35$. There will be a big white column around $a=3.5$. It is an interesting graph.

Comment: @Dan The "white columns" correspond to values of the parameter for which there are periodic orbits

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, and I suspect that for every (or nearly every?) $a$, the sequence cycles through a finite number of values. It would seem strange if, when we increase $a$, the number of values jumps from finite to infinite, then back to finite, etc.

Comment: After reading https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html I now think that the sequence in my question is dense in some intervals, for certain values of $a$. As we increase $a$, we reach an "accumulation point" at which the sequence becomes chaotic. Then further increasing $a$ leads to a sudden end to chaos, then back to chaos, ad infinitum.